# How to check if number of checked checkbox is multiply of 3 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

In my `ul` `li` tags and i want to when sumbit pressed, check if number of checked checkbox isn't muliply of 3, display alert. How i achive this?

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />a</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />b</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />c</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />d</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />e</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />f</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="go" />
```

Comment: `select only muliply of 3` can you expand on this?

Comment: Do you want select only every third select or must select 3 child ?

Comment: if user select 4 check box and click continue it show plz select multiply of 3

Comment: so you can select 6?

Comment: 3,6,9(multiplay of 3) it will continue but rest it will show error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get length of `checked` checkbox and use the `%` (modulus) operator to check number is multiple of `3`. If number is multiple of `3` result will be `0`.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    var length = $("ul :checkbox:checked").length;
    if (length == 0 || length  % 3 != 0)
        console.log("Select multiply of 3");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />a</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />b</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />c</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />d</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />e</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />f</li>
</ul>
<button>Continue</button>
```

Comment: Will not work in case none of the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @RanjitSingh Good mention.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check the number of selected checkbox using

```
$("#chkboxes").find("input:checked").length;
```

your html

```
<ul id="chkboxes">
  <li><input type="checkbox" />a</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />b</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />c</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />d</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />e</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" />f</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="checkvalues()">Submit</button><span id="msg"></span>
```

Js

```
function checkvalues(){
var count = $("#chkboxes").find("input:checked").length;

$("#msg").text(count>0 && count%3==0?"multiple of 3 selected!":"please select multiple of 3");

}
```

You can check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hp7fuvfa/)